# Python OpenCV's basic commands "Cannot find reference in '__init__'.py

Tags: python, opencv

While starting a new project, OpenCV just decided to stop working on my PC and laptop. I'm using Python 3.9. Basic commands like "imread" and "imshow" aren't working anymore.
I've uninstalled and reinstalled Python and Pycharm. I've removed the module and reinstalled it... yet and it still won't function properly. This is an error I've never seen before.

```
import cv2 as cv

img = "Nemo.jpg"
cv.imread(img)
cv.imshow("feesh", img)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ae\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv.imshow("feesh", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

[Cannot find reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueaCJ.png)
[Actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBotX.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having this issue with OpenCV 4.6.0.66. It's not a perfect solution, but you can roll back to an older version with `pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache -U opencv-python==4.5.5.62`.
There's more discussion/explanation [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20997#issuecomment-1205634085)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was also opened on GitHub in Issues for opencv repo. Somebody showed [solution](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20997#issuecomment-1328068006). You just should add `C:\path-to-python\Lib\site-packages\cv2` to interpreter paths in PyCharm's settings. Look there:

[image: the way to solve the problem]